# How to replace duplicated rows with "." in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates

I need to substitute duplications in my first column with just "."

For example:

```
name1
name1
name1
name2
name2
name3
name3
```

And I need Output:

```
name1
.
.
name2
.
name3
.
```

I have solution like this:

```
awk '{c=$1} c==p{gsub(/./,".",$1)} {p=c} 1' in.file
```

But the output is:

```
name1
.....
.....
name2
.....
name3
.....
```

Is there any solution without any other piping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array to check if a line has already been seen!

```
$ awk 'seen[$0]++ {$0="."}1' file
name1
.
.
name2
.
name3
.
```

The typical way to skip repeated lines is to say `awk '!seen[$0]++' file`. Here we use the same logic but twisting it a little bit: we use the array `seen[]` to check if a line has appeared so far. If it has, `seen[$0]++` will be bigger than 0, so `{$0="."}` will occur. Then, `1` prints either this or the line.

If you happen to need this to check not the full line but a defined column, do replace `$0` (full record) with `$n`, where `n` is the n<sup>th</sup> field.

Comment: And if I want to apply uniq only for the first column (I have more columns in this file) - it is possible to use awk 'uniq[$1]++ {$1="."}1' file ??

Comment: @Geroge test it :) But yes, it should work the way you say.

Comment: Ok you answered earlier than my question was posted... Excelent solution! Very very thank you for so fast reply!!!

Comment: a ++ for being so elegant with the solution. ;)

Comment: This answer will replace `name1` if it appears beyond the first run of `name1`-s.

Comment: @MateiDavid which is what the OP expects to happen, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure what he expects, but his "adjusted" initial solution doesn't do that.

Comment: @MateiDavid : And that's what op wants. isn't it? Or probably `'uniq[$1]++ {$0="."}1' `

Comment: Yes my problem was inside awk code - awk '{c=$1} c==p{gsub(/./,".",$1)} {p=c} 1' in.file, the good solution is like @MateiDavid pointed - replace with - * : awk '{c=$1} c==p{gsub(/.*/,".",$1)} {p=c} 1'.

Comment: `^1` for the concise, efficient solution. The array's usually named `seen` though...

Answer (score 3):

This function call:

```
gsub(/./,".",$1)
```

replaces *each* match of the pattern `/./` with the string `"."`.  The regex given matches any single character, so you are requesting exactly the behavior you observe: each character in the duplicate names is replaced with a ".".

There are many ways to fix it; among them would be to perform the substitution you really mean:

```
sub(/.*/, ".", $1)
```

That's not the *best* implementation, but it demonstrates the issue in your original code.

Comment: Thank you John. Very useful to use sub.

Comment: @Geroge, you're welcome, but do note that the key point is not so much to use `sub()` instead of `gsub()`, but rather to use the appropriate regex for what you want to accomplish: `/.*/` instead of `/./`.  Using `sub()` is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a `*` to your pattern inside `gsub`, to match the entire row:

```
awk '{c=$1} c==p{gsub(/.*/,".",$1)} {p=c} 1'
```

Comment: right but then you don't need gsub(), just sub() as shown in [@JohnBollinger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38853971/1745001).